# Delete specific chat message from a Quickblox dialog

Tags: ios, xcode, quickblox

In my app, I am implementing quick blox. I have an issue in deleting chat messages. I want to delete selected chat messages. My steps are:

- Getting array of messages for a specific dialog id.
- Getting selected message id's and adding them in NSSet.
- Request from quickblox server to delete.

I am getting response successfully. But when I again create dialog for this ID I also get the deleted messages. And when I restart my application and create dialog for this Id, Its working fine and I don't get deleted messages. My code is.

```
NSMutableSet *messagesToBeDeleteSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init];
NSArray *keysArray = [idxDictionary allKeys];
if([keysArray count] > 0)
{
    for(int counter=0; counter<[keysArray count]; counter++)
    {
        NSInteger value = [[idxDictionary objectForKey:[keysArray objectAtIndex:counter]] integerValue];

        if([[[ChatService shared] messagsForDialogId:self.dialog.ID] count] > 0)
        {
            QBChatMessage *message = [[[ChatService shared] messagsForDialogId:self.dialog.ID] objectAtIndex:value];
            [messagesToBeDeleteSet addObject:message.ID];

        }
    }
}

[QBRequest deleteMessagesWithIDs:messagesToBeDeleteSet successBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

    NSLog(@"success");

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    NSLog(@"deleteMessageWithID error:%@", response.error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete that messeges from Local also.

like I have use for single messege

```
  - (void)removeMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message forDialogId:(NSString *)dialogId
   {
      NSMutableArray *messagesArray = [self.messages objectForKey:dialogId];
      if(messagesArray != nil){

      [messagesArray removeObject:message];

      [self sortMessages:messagesArray];
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Swift 5 :

**Things we should know before deleting message.**

If you are the owner of the message (i.e. Your message)

- You can delete message for everyone OR for yourself also

If you are not the owner of the message (i.e. opponent user's message)

- You can delete that message for you only (cannot delete for everyone)

Below API is Used to delete message

```
   //You can delete single or multiple messages by using single API. (need message id's)

    QBRequest.deleteMessages(withIDs: Set(arrayLiteral:"54fdbb69535c12c2e407c672","54fdbb69535c12c2e407c673"), forAllUsers: true, successBlock: { (response) in
    print("Deleted Successfully")


    }) { (err) in
       print("Failed")
  }
```

If you pass `true` to the `forAllUsers` parameter and you are the owner of the message, then message will be deleted for ALL users. If you pass `false` to the `forAllUsers` parameter, then it will be deleted only for current user and other users will still have it.